# How to print following pattern getting issue with spaces?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am trying to write the code but not getting how to achieve expected output
Causing issue with space and not able to make proper judgement how to get exact spaces after every iteration

**My code :**

```
n=15
cnt=0
lst=[str(' ') for x in range(1,n+1)]
initial_length=len(''.join(lst))
print(initial_length)
for row in range(1,n+1):
  lst[cnt-1]=str(row)
  cnt=cnt-1
  print(' '.join(lst))
```

**Output of above code is not as expected output**

```
                            1
                          2 1
                        3 2 1
                      4 3 2 1
                    5 4 3 2 1
                  6 5 4 3 2 1
                7 6 5 4 3 2 1
              8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
            9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
          10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
        11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
    13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Expected output :**

```
                                  1
                                2 1                                                                 
                              3 2 1                                                              
                            4 3 2 1
                          5 4 3 2 1                         
                        6 5 4 3 2 1                       
                      7 6 5 4 3 2 1                     
                    8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
                  9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
               10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
            11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
         12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
      13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
   14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that two digits take up more space than one digit (or one space), also you can simplify to `lst = ['' for _ in range(n)]` or `lst = [''] * n`, but as I said you need to account for double digits taking up more space than a single space

Comment: @Matiiss : That is the thing i want to achieve any way to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to account for larger digits taking up more space, which means that when creating the list that contains spaces, you need to multiply the space by how many digits are in that number which you can get by `len(str(number))`:

```py
n = 15

# create a list containing how many spaces each number will take up
# in reverse order because the figure is reverse
lst = [' ' * len(str(x)) for x in range(n, 0, -1)]

# go over each number
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    # replace the digit in its place from end
    # by the string represantion of itself
    lst[-x] = str(x)
    # print joined list
    print(' '.join(lst))
```

Also:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations. Object method definitions have one blank line around them.

Comment: Awsome bro thanks let me try to understand what it is doing step by step

Comment: @Matiiss : can you elaborate why their is a need of  `lst.copy()`

Comment: @codeholic24 actually there is no need, I rewrote the code to a much shorter and more understandable one. I just thought that modifying the list containing those spaces would change the result, now there is a much better version of this, without the need to create multiple lists and stuff (so more memory efficient too)

Comment: @Matiiss : I also answered kindly check below. That's the reason I ask you why their is a reason of using `lst.copy()`. Cool thanks for changing your solution making it more memory efficient

Answer (score 1):

Another approximation, by knowing the quantity of spaces in advance using a recursive function:

```py
def findDigits(N):
    if N <= 1:
        return N
    # Changing number to string
    s = str(N)
    # Add length of number to total_sum
    return len(s) + findDigits(N - 1)


def print_inverse_pyramid(n):
    # Calculate number of total digits until n
    total_digits = findDigits(n)
    # Print the pyramid
    for row in range(1, n + 1):
        total_digits -= len(str(row))
        l_r = [str(i) for i in range(row, 0, -1)]
        print(" " * (total_digits + (n - row)) + " ".join(l_r))

print_inverse_pyramid(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: 'looking' at the last line

```
n = 15

def serie(n):
    return ' '.join([str(j) for j in range(n, 0, -1)])

maxlen = len(serie(n))
for i in range(1, n +1):
    s = serie(i)
    print(" " * (maxlen - len(s)) + s)
```

With math, computing the length as the sum of the int of the log10 of values and adding for the spaces

```
import math

n = 15

def lenserie(n):
    return sum(map(lambda i : int(math.log(i, 10)) + 1 ,range(1, n+1))) + (n-1)

maxlen = lenserie(n)
for i in range(1, n+1):
    print(" " * (maxlen - lenserie(i)) + " ".join([str(i) for i in range(i, 0, -1)]))
```